# Creating an <ins> element for advertising at load time, without JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, creation

Typically, a Google ad can be declared as following in a HTML document:

```
<div id="myAds">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890"
         data-ad-slot="0987654321">
    </ins>
</div>
```

However, I need to insert that ad element conditionally when the page is loaded. How can I create such an `<ins>` element dynamically in Javascript? I am looking for a code example without JQuery.

Comment: Presumably you will also have to call the google code that parses the `<ins>` again.  It's my understanding that Google doesn't like dynamic changing of ads though, but maybe that doesn't apply to this situation.

Comment: Yes and yes. I am aware of Google's policies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the following does the job:

```
    var myAds = document.getElementById("myAds");

    var frag, elem;

    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    elem = document.createElement('ins');

    frag.appendChild(elem);

    elem.className += "adsbygoogle";
    elem.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px");
    elem.setAttribute("data-ad-client", "ca-pub-1234567890");
    elem.setAttribute("data-ad-slot", "0987654321");

    myAds.appendChild(frag);
```